# Enforcing schema validation in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm looking for ways to validate that data being inserted into MongoDB matches a schema, e.g. has all the required fields and correct data types.  I know Mongo itself is schemaless, but if I could validate the data at the application level before passing it to the Mongo driver, that'd be good.

I've looked at JSON-Schema.  My biggest hesitation there is that I can only find one Java library for schema validation, and I don't know whether I should trust it, I prefer libraries backed by Apache or Google.

I've also looked at Apache Thrift, Avro, and Protocol Buffers, which aren't specifically validation frameworks, but they do each have a concept of a schema.  I'd be interested if there's a way to piggy-back off of one of those to perform validation.

Any suggestions?  Or should I embrace the schemalessness of Mongo and not even bother trying to validate the data?

Comment: Not everything is made by the apache foundation or Google, i.e. Facebook makes stuff too. And no, you should validate the data, one common method is by using an active record model to validate a set of defined attributes

Comment: Thanks, and I probably should have clarified my statement about Apache and Google as to not come off too snobbish.  I like to pick projects that have a strong track record of support from the developers or community.  So whether that's Apache or a single developer in his basement, it doesn't matter as long as I have some confidence that if a bug is found in the library five years down the road I'll have a good path to getting it fixed.

Comment: Yea I see what you mean there :) it is a always a problem with software closed or open source as I have found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the upcoming **Mongo 3.2 version** they added [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document-validation/) ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewjamesmorgan/document-validation-in-mongodb-32)).

You can specify validation rules for each collection, using [validator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#validator) option using almost all mongo query operators (except `$geoNear`, `$near`, `$nearSphere`, `$text`, and `$where`). You can read more about it in one  of my [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602507/1090562).

Comment: But per my understanding, the document validation in MongoDB is not validation against a schema (XSD, or JSON Schema).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're still looking but an object document mapper (ODM) would do the trick.

I have checked out both [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) or [Spring Data - MongoDB](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb) and either would take care of your type safety concerns since they would map your documents directly to Java classes.