# Sub-document validation receives array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Parent schema (Dashboard) that contains children (Widget).

The problem is that I need to validate single widget, but `.pre('save')` receives array of widgets.

Is there any way to validate single property? I tried to add `widgetSize: { type: String, validate: xxx }`, but with no luck.

```
var widgetSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  measurement: { type: String, required: true },
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  key: { type: String, default: '' },
  background: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: false },
  localeId: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, default: false },
  hintText: String,
  widgetSize: { type: String }
});

widgetSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log(this);
  if(!sizeValidator(this.widgetSize)) {
    return next(new Error('Size format was incorrect: ' + this.widgetSize));
  }
  next();
});

var dashboardSchema = new Schema({
  slug: { type: String, required: true },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  backgroundImage: String,
  defaultDashboard: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  backgroundColor: String,
  widgets: [widgetSchema]
});
```

The code to add a sub-documents

```
dashboard.widgets.push(widgetToCreate);
return dashboard.saveAsync(); // promisified
```

Comment: In Mongo 3.2 there will be validation. May be it can be helpful to [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33602507/1090562)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were using `this` to validate the subdoc value which as you noticed is set to the top level document. More directly, you can use the value passed to the validate function like so:

```
var widgetSchema = new Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  measurement: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  key: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
  },
  background: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: false
  },
  localeId: {
    type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    default: false
  },
  hintText: String,
  widgetSize: {
    type: String,
    validate: function widgetSizeValidate(val) {
      return val === 'foobar';
    }
  }
});
```