# Validate data from MongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am fetching data from MongoDB using java program. MongoDB data contains:

```
{
"gender": "female",
"city": "ABC",
"phone": "+1 (995) 441-2988",
"email": "undefined.undefined@.info",
"date": "2015-08-11T15:55:00 -06:-30",
"age": 37,}
```

Need to validate data like city should be string value, age should be integer, etc. Is there any quick way to use MongoDB queries in java to validate this?

Comment: Use **[$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/)**

Comment: How to use it in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB [$type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) selects the documents where the value of the field is an instance of the specified numeric BSON type.

As per your document structure `date` field is not actual `ISODATE` it looks like `String` so it's data type `2` and `age` default data type `1 like double` so your java code as

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("gender",new BasicDBObject("$type",2));
query.put("city",new BasicDBObject("$type",2));
query.put("phone",new BasicDBObject("$type",2));
query.put("email",new BasicDBObject("$type",2));
query.put("date",new BasicDBObject("$type",2));
query.put("age", new BasicDBObject("$type",1));

    DBCursor cursorDoc  =  collection.find(query);
    while (cursorDoc.hasNext()) {
        BasicDBObject object = (BasicDBObject) cursorDoc.next();
        System.out.println(object);
    }
```

Comment: if I have "city" : "ABC123", what query should be used to get city having only characters,it does not contain any digit.

Comment: You want to run same query in mongo shell?

Comment: if I give city as abc123 it is considering it as string. So it is giving that record as valid record

Comment: yes it is valid record because you entered city like `city:"abc123"` is String not number if you insert `city:123` then it invalid because `123` consider as number not string , If you confused about data type then read this [mongo type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) it will helpful to find out which documents are valid or not

Comment: can we use $regex to check number or string ?

Comment: yes should use `regex` to check given string contains number or not .

Answer (score 0):

In the upcoming **Mongo 3.2 version** they added [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document-validation/) ([slides](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewjamesmorgan/document-validation-in-mongodb-32)).

You can specify validation rules for each collection, using [validator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#validator) option using almost all mongo query operators (except `$geoNear`, `$near`, `$nearSphere`, `$text`, and `$where`).

Based on your requirements, it is enough to achieve what you want with just checking type. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33602507/1090562).