# Validating Mongo Documents in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, validation, jersey

I'm writing a rest service using spring boot with Jersey and MongoDB starter packages. So I have validation working on top level documents by creating the beans:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoValidationBeans {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

I have a document:

```
@Document
public class SomeDocument {
    @NotEmpty(message="error message that shows on console")
    private Set<NonDocumentObject> referencesToOtherDocuments;
}
```

With set of embedded objects:

```
public class NonDocumentObject {
    @NotNull(message="can't see this error message")
    private ObjectId referenceId;
    @NotBlank
    private String referenceInfo;
}
```

The validation beans respect the @NotEmpty annotation on my set of objects, but they do not respect @NotNull or @NotBlank annotations on fields on my NonDocumentObject. How can I get validation to work on the fields of my embedded Set of objects.

EDIT: @Valid fixes the above problem.

Also, when a constraint violation happens on my top level document, I can see the specific message on my console but tomcat returns an http error page with response status 400. How can I instead send a json object with more information about the error? I have a class

```
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {}
```

which catches 404, 405, etc exceptions and returns a json object with the appropriate information, but does not catch mongo constraint validations. I think I need to throw exceptions from the mongo validation beans but can't find resources that direct me how to.

I also want to be able to embed other objects into NonDocumentObject with its own validation. Would it be possible?

Comment: In Mongo 3.2 there will be validation. May be it can be helpful to [take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33602507/1090562)

Answer (score 0):

So the @Valid annotation triggers cascade validation, but I still can't figure out how to catch validation errors with an exception mapper, or some other way to catch validation errors.